# php file redirect via mod_rewrite to new subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect wp-login.php to a new url elsewhere, I thought it was correct but my syntax is off.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://admin.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What I am trying to achive is if wp-login.php is called and the url is not admin.domain.com it will redirect to admin.domain.com/wp-login.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way and see if this works for you.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://admin.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```